# What does the following set function mean?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am just looking at some basic textbook on set theory, and one of the exercises wants me to deduce what is the range of such function:

$g(x) = x + 22$

where the domain is $\{ 1, 2, 3 \}$

Is the range going to be $\{ 1, 2, 3, 22 \}$ ? Does $+$ denote insertion in this case?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I think $+$ denotes addition; $g(1)=1+22=23$, for example

Comment: In other words the range of this set is {23, 24, 25} ?

Comment: Yes; it could also be called the image

Comment: To combine sets, the usual notation is $\{1,2,3\}\color{red}\cup\{22\}=\{1,2,3,22\}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think $+$ denotes addition here,

and the exercise is asking for the set of outputs of the function that adds $22$,

viz. $\{2\color{red}3,24,25\}$ if the inputs are in $\{1,2,3\}$.